# Microsoft logger does not print information to the console

Tags: c#, .net-core, logging, dependency-injection

I have a question about Microsoft Logger. I wrote a simple console application with dependency injection my problem is that logger does not write to the console if the code

```
   using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
    {
        builder.AddConsole();
    });
```

is commented. I want to understand why it is behaving in such way.

I have a simple program

```
using LoggerExamples;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection = ConfigureSerices(serviceCollection);
serviceCollection.AddTransient<FirstExample>();

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
RunApplication(serviceCollection, serviceProvider);

//using var loggerFactory = LoggerFactory.Create(builder =>
//{
//    builder.AddConsole();
//});

IServiceCollection ConfigureSerices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    return serviceCollection.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
}

static void RunApplication(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var firstExample = serviceProvider.GetService<FirstExample>();
    serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    firstExample?.Run();
}
```

Injected class looks like

```
   public class FirstExample
    {
        ILogger<FirstExample> _logger;

        public FirstExample(ILogger<FirstExample> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("TEST");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just as XAMT did, I copy pasted your code into an empty Visual Studio 2022 .NET 6 console application, added the (3) required NuGet packages (for logging and DI) and ran the code. Conslusion: it logs to the console. This means that there's something happening that you don't show in your question, which means the problem is not reproducible. I therefore voted it to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Your code is working without Logger Factory Configuration.

```
using ConsoleApp13_Net6;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

IServiceCollection serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection = ConfigureSerices(serviceCollection);
serviceCollection.AddScoped<FirstExample>();

var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
RunApplication(serviceCollection, serviceProvider);

IServiceCollection ConfigureSerices(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
{
    return serviceCollection.AddLogging(configure => configure.AddConsole());
}

static void RunApplication(IServiceCollection serviceCollection, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var firstExample = serviceProvider.GetService<FirstExample>();
    serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
    firstExample?.Run();
}
```

Result :

[image: Logging Test in Net6 Console Application]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but for me, it is not working. I am using .net standard 6, with the newest versions of the libraries. 
image https://freeimage.host/i/Xh9p5B

Comment: @Gurult, please share the whole solution with git or any tools , I was curious about this.